# Convenient way of copying a sequence into an array axis if they differ in length?

Tags: python, numpy

Hello fellow programmers!

I want to copy a `sequence` of length `3` into an `array` of dimensions `4x5`:

```
import numpy as np


ar = np.zeros((4, 5))
print(ar)

data = [1,2,3]
ar[0] = data
print(ar)
```

Output:

```
[[0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]
 [0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]
 [0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]
 [0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]]
```

Error:

```
    ar[0] = data
ValueError: cannot copy sequence with size 3 to array axis with dimension 5
```

I was hoping to find a convenient way to get this output:

```
[[1. 2. 3. 0. 0.]
 [0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]
 [0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]
 [0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]]
```

without having to loop through each array element. Is there a way to do this?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Index a slice of `ar` that matches `data` shape.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want this!

```
ar[0, range(len(data))] = data 

ar
array([[1., 2., 3., 0., 0.],
       [0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
       [0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
       [0., 0., 0., 0., 0.]])
```

Note: Will throw IndexError if the `data` length is more than second dim in the array.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with `ar[0][:3]`

```
import numpy as np


ar = np.zeros((4, 5))
print(ar)

data = [1,2,3]
ar[0][:3] = data
print(ar)

[[0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]
 [0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]
 [0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]
 [0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]]
[[1. 2. 3. 0. 0.]
 [0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]
 [0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]
 [0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]]
```

Comment: Why not use `ar[0, :3] = data`?  It's clearer `numpy` syntax.

Comment: @hpaulj You might be right about it being more clear.  I don't use `numpy` very frequently so I'm not familiar with the conventions.  Apparently, OP agrees with you about that being preferred.

Comment: Though even in the accepted answer I'd prefer the `:3` slice over the `range(3)`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```py
ar[0][:len(data)] = data
```

if you know that `data` will be shorter than the first dimension of `ar`.

If `data` might be longer than this, you can make the desired 2D array with:

```py
d = np.array(data)
d.resize((4,5))
print(d)
```

Note that `d.resize(shape)` pads with zeroes whereas `np.resize(d,shape)` would repeat the elements of `d` until the array is full.

Answer (score 0):

Although **Dishin Ha Goyani** gave the correct answer to this question I wanted to give further insight on the same problem with more dimensional arrays.

The Original Problem was that I wanted to copy an array of dimensions `(39, 7, 242)` into an array of dimensions `(4, 39, 12, 242)` with length differences lying at `7` and `12`.

The best I could come up with is this:

```
import numpy as np

ar = np.zeros((4, 39, 12, 242))
data = np.ones((39, 7, 242))

for idx_1, layer_1 in enumerate(ar):
    for idx_2, layer_2 in enumerate(layer_1):
        ar[idx_1][idx_2][range(len(data[idx_2]))] = data[idx_2]
```